# Crontab - run command random time

Tags: python, random, cron

I have created a cron job in which it runs a command within random value (Example 10 mins) at 11pm everyday. I found this example online but I can not find reference.

What I have that doesn't work

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
LOCAL_CONFIG_DIR=/user/folder
    0  11  *   *   * sleep $(($RANDOM \% 10))m && python /user/folder/file.py
```

The following works but does not run at random 10 mins:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
LOCAL_CONFIG_DIR=/user/folder

0  11  *   *   * python /user/folder/file.py
```

Wonder if my issue is with `$Random`?

Comment: `cron` tasks are executed in a "shell" with limited builtins and environment.  Probably `$RANDOM` isn't available, and possibly even `$((` is a problem.  One solution would be to put the entire task definition, including the random timing bit, in a separate `bash` script and then crontab the script.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to implement the randomness in the script being called instead of trying to do it inside cron.  Some crons do have a way to delay execution by a random amount, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I might try execute the bash script to see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really good with bash, but You surely can implement sleep inside your python scipt.

```
import random
import time
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10)*60)

#Your actual script goes here
```